# Spring Security : configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) vs authenticationManagerBean()

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, authentication, spring-security

I am configuring Spring Security. To authenticate and authorize users, I override `configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)` of `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`. This works fine. Below is my code:

```java
@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth
        .userDetailsService(customUserDetailsService)
        .passwordEncoder(getPasswordEncoder());
}
```

But when I try to to enable method level security, per action, using      `@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)` it throws an exception:

> No AuthenticationManager found

As per my understanding `AuthenticationManager` is used to authenticate and authorize users, which I was already doing using `configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)` and Spring was injecting `auth` object itself.

Why I need to register `AuthenticationManager` manually?

```java
@Bean @Override
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
    return super.authenticationManagerBean();
}
```

What are the differennt purposes  `configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)` and `authenticationManagerBean()` serves?

I am extending `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`. Why I need to provide a custom `AuthenticationManager` by overriding `authenticationManagerBean()`.

Answer (score 9):

Your configuration class extends [`WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.8.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.html), which only configures web security (not method security):

> Provides a convenient base class for creating a `WebSecurityConfigurer` instance. The implementation allows customization by overriding methods.

So your `AuthenticationManager` is only used for web security.

If you want to configure (change the defaults) method security, you can extend [`GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.8.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/method/configuration/GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration.html):

> Base `Configuration` for enabling global method security. Classes may extend this class to customize the defaults, but must be sure to specify the `EnableGlobalMethodSecurity` annotation on the subclass.

To configure `AuthenticationManager` for method security, you can

1. overwrite [`GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration#configure`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.8.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/method/configuration/GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration.html#configure(org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder)):

   > Sub classes can override this method to register different types of authentication. If not overridden, `configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder)` will attempt to autowire by type.
2. expose your `AuthenticationManager` as a bean that can be autowired by  `GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration`, see [`WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter#authenticationManagerBean`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.8.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.html#authenticationManagerBean()):

   > Override this method to expose the `AuthenticationManager` from `configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder)` to be exposed as a Bean.
3. use only one global `AuthenticationManager` by autowiring the global `AuthenticationManagerBuild`, see [Spring Security 3.2.0.RC2 Released](https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/spring-security-3-2-0-rc2-released#objectpostprocessor-quiesent-postprocessor-removed):

   > For example, if you want to configure global authentication (i.e. you only have a single AuthenticationManager) you should autowire the AuthenticationMangerBuilder:
   >
   > ```
   > @Autowired
   > public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) {
   >     // ... configure it ...
   > }
   > ```